# Checking size on multiple mysql tables and schemas

Tags: mysql, database

The space on my database server ran out, and I want a quick way to view all the tables on all schemas, and how much size each table takes. How do I do that?

If I could find the fattest schemas and work my way from there, that's also good.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the **SHOW TABLE STATUS** command 
in MySQL. If you go to your MySQL prompt and select a database, then use 
the SHOW TABLE STATUS command, like this:

```
show table status like '%';
```

you'll find a column called Data_length which tells you "the length of 
the data file" for each table. If you simply add the size of each table 
in the database together, you should have the size of the whole 
database.

If you run the query which is given below in MySQL Query Browser then you will get the two columns first will display the Data Base Name and the second will display the Data Base Size in MB.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

Comment: Can I do it for all the schemas at ones?

Answer (score 4):

simply `cd PATH_TO_DATABASE_DATA;`

> for db in `find -type d `; do du -shc $db/*; done | less

or using maxdepth

> for db in `find -type d -maxdepth 1 `; do du -shc $db/*.{MYI,MYD,frm}; done | less

if want to sort

> for db in `find -type d -maxdepth 1 `; do ls -alS $db/*.{MYI,MYD,frm}; done | less

```
*.MYI = index size
*.MYD = data size
*.frm = table schema size
```

Comment: Nice work - all that's needed now is sorting it by size. Linux is not my strong suit. See also - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/how-to-understand-whats-taking-up-space/3964#3964

Answer (score 1):

You should use SHOW TABLE STATUS: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-table-status.html

SHOW TABLE STATUS works likes SHOW TABLES, but provides a lot of information about each non-TEMPORARY table.